# Creating "Append-Only" Comment Field in Custom SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint, custom-lists

I am relatively new to SharePoint, working with WSS SharePoint 2.0.  The "Issues" list template contains an "append-only" comment column.  The great thing about this append-only comment column is that it saves a history of the comments entered every time you save, and it clears out the comment field for the next time you edit the item. 
I would like to add this column to a custom list.  However, when I add a new column, it does not give me an option to add this type of comment column - it only gives options for single or multiple lines of text.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about WSS 2.0 (aka SharePoint2003) or WSS 3.0 (aka SharePoint 2007)?
WSS2 doesn't have an "append only" comment field on Issues lists - it keeps previous versions of the whole record.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an append-only column by choosing the Multiple Lines of Text option and selecting "Append Changes to Existing Text". I believe this only applies to lists, not document libraries. Other kinds of lists may restrict this, too.

Comment: You will only see this option if versioning is turned on for the list. If a new version is created without a new comment, it will appear empty unless you're viewing the full history (like in a display form).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I am using Sharepoint 2003, and it doesn't appear to give me an option to turn on versioning - so the "Append Changes to Existing Text" option does not come up when adding a "Multiple Lines of Text" column.  Is turning on versioning not an option in WSS 2.0 (Sharepoint 2003)?

Comment: Your comment on this not being available in Document libraries was the info I needed

Answer (score 1):

if you're using SharePoint 2007, In the List/Library Settings click Add from existing site columns.  Under Base Columns Append-Only Comments should be there.  In order for the "tracking" to work *Versioning must be enabled for that list/library*.

Answer (score 0):

Not having an append-only field in a document library made me pretty sad. But this template made me happy again:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=02C4D1B4-7D53-4B72-B577-3DA23F86EC17&displaylang=en

It's the Document Library and Review template and allows each document to have a "Discuss" button and related discussion thread.